# Как правильно прописывать путь к файлам в PHP?

Tags: php

Как лучше прописывать путь к файлу в PHP?

Так:

```
require_once(dirName(__FILE__).'/header.inc.php');
```

Или так:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/func.inc.php');
```

Что Вы посоветуете и почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забавный вопрос... С PHP 5.3 есть константа `__DIR__`, `__DIR__ == dirName(__FILE__);` - но это так, к слову. Прописывая пути через `__DIR__`, Вы строите структуру путей относительно файла, в котором происходит обращение, а используя `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - от корня. ИМХО, что использовать - выбор очевиден.

Answer (score 1):

Если в будущем не менять структуру проекта то выбор отправной точки для указания пути это дело вкуса. Но в тоже время указания от корня это более корректный выбор с точки зрения читаемости и не только.